# F5 LTM 10.2 and MSSQL 08R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, load-balancing, database-mirroring, f5-big-ip

We have a mirrored SQL server setup with a pair of LTM's holding the mirror VIP.  We're trying to setup a health monitor that runs a query against both servers in the mirror and directs traffic to the principal.  Right now we have a query running that should only be possible on the active side of the mirror, but it's showing that both nodes are green.  Any ideas?

Comment: Any updates? Im looking to do the same thing. Im thinking it would need a query of a specific DB. Im thinking along this line - exec sp_dbmmonitorresults [DB Name] If the Role returns a 2 its passive. If 1 its active. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mirroring_role_desc FROM sys.database_mirroring WHERE database_id=(Your database number) --expected response = 'MIRROR' or 'PRINCIPAL'
```

Answer (score 0):

F5 can't natively support queries directly against a database. As such, this may be why you are having an issue. You may want to look into [external health monitors](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/ltm-external-monitors-the-basics)